# What is the use of the select statement in SQL(ite) triggers?

Tags: trigger, select, sqlite

In SQLite, triggers may contain four types of statements: insert, update, delete, and select. What is the use of the select statement, namely, how can I access the result-set of the select statement?

For example, with the following setup,

```
create table "Data" ("data" Text);
create trigger "Data-AI" after insert on "Data" begin
    /* some insert, update, or delete statements */
    select "data" as "selected" from "Data" where length("data") < 4;
            -- assume that there at least two rows in the result set
    /* some insert, update, or delete statements */
end;
```

how can I use `"selected"` in the second batch of insert, update, or delete statements?

Answer (score 3):

In a trigger body, the result of a SELECT statement is simply thrown away.

Using a SELECT statement makes sense only for its side effects, i.e., when using a user-defined function, or RAISE().

Comment: Is this documented?